Understanding DC versus AC in synthesizers
Can someone please explain the difference between DC and AC?
Especially in these scenarios:

Envelope that goes from 0 V to 5 V over time and back to 0 V
Square wave that oscillates between -5 V and +5 V is AC, right? But what about a square wave that oscillates between 0 V and 5 V?
Sine wave LFO that oscillates between ±3 V is considered AC - but if I will offset it and make it oscillate between 0 V and 6 V, will it still be considered AC?

Any further explanations would be great!

While it may be presented as a hard fact that this is AC and that is DC and never the twain shall meet, it's actually much more a matter of opinion. I personally would consider every signal to have an AC component (which may be zero) on top of a DC component (which may be zero).

You have time varying periodicaly oscillating signals. In no book they would be called "DC". (Similar questions have been asked before and always end up in debate on definitions and their semantings of whether the voltage or current polarity alternates. And it does not matter a bit if those signals are defined as being pulsating DC or AC, the signals don't change no matter how you define them - DC signals with AC on top of them, or AC signals with DC offset on them, even if the offset is 0V). Same is true whether the signals relate to synthesizers or not.

what difference does it make to you?

This is just a recommendation, but I think it's more useful than talking about AC and DC: In the context of anything called "synthesizer", the categories "AC" and "DC" are not sufficient to describe anything of importance. Simply forget about them, and think in terms of frequency components.

Comments above are useful. My answer effectively expands on these.

CLOSE VOTERS I reopened & answered this question. I consider it was more "essentially trivial" than opinion based. I also consider that answering it provides useful future material as per site guidelines (even if trivial to most). || I welcome comment on this reopening. I am entirely happy for people to disagree with me. My aim is to  try and learn what we jointly think and why and establish how we approach various things in future.||I somewhat feel that many people find it easier to close-vote than to guide newer-comers. I understand the time pressures involved. Input welcome.

I assume that "synthesizer" describes something that produces audio waveforms.
While differentiating AC and DC is notionally opinion based, in most cases the descriptions are clear enough. While this answer therefore deals somewhat in "opinions" the following understanding of opinions is liable to be accepted in 99%+ of cases.
In general situations whether or not the the time variant component is of importance to the application is the key factor. DCis a voltage where any AC component is irrelevant or is minimised to improve te DC's integrity. AC is any votage where the time variant component is of significance. Where AC and DC components both matter it's essentially AC.

An eg 5V DC power supply with 0.1 VAC RMS ripple IS DC but HAS AC ripple.
A 5V DC power supply with 3 VAC RMS ripple is a faulty DC power supply.
A synthesiser with a 5 VDC output with 3 VAC signal superimposed (same as the DC faulty power supply above) is AC in a sound or music context - but  how you describe it may depend on how you are using it. eg if it was being filtered and used to control some form of on/off "gate" the DC component may be most relevant.

In your examples, in general terms 1. MAY be considered DC if usually at 0 or 5V and transition period is largely irrelevant. eg a power supply output.
ALL others are AC. Reference point is irrelevant.
In a synthesiser, case 1. is probably usually AC if it controls any aspect of audio output. eg envelope magnitude. If the change from minimum to maximum and back is an on/off switching function where time taken is largely irrelevant then you could call it DC.
